# .replace() to Work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

Here is my script. It currently works in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = $('.header-image').css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
var bgImgWidth = img.width;
var bgImgHeight = img.height;

var imageRatio = bgImgHeight / bgImgWidth;
var boxWidth = $(window).width();
var imageHeight = imageRatio * boxWidth;

$(img).load(function () {
  $('.header-image').css('height', imageHeight);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  var newImageWidth = imageRatio * $(window).width();
  $('.header-image').css('height', newImageWidth);
});
```

I think it has something to do with the .replace(/url(|)$/ig, ""), but I can't figure out how to get it to work in both. Any idea on what is going on?

When I threw these in the mix:

```
alert( img.src );
console.log($('.header-image').css('background-image'));
```

The first returned an url, the second returned

```
url(http://example.com/path/to/photo.jpg)
```

Comment: What does `$('.header-image').css('background-image')` return?

Comment: `url\(|\)$` matches either `url(` anywhere or `)` at the end of the string. Is this really what you expect? Isn’t there a semicolon missing?

Comment: Regarding the missing semicolon, I copied this piece from someone else, so I'm not sure.

I have posted the return values in the question.

Comment: The second alert doesn't help because the selector is wrong. It'd be better to use the console for debugging instead of alerts.

Comment: Also, the most probable reason for the problem is that image dimensions aren't available before the image has loaded. You should move those calculations inside the load handler.

Comment: @lawdawg write `console.log($('.header-image').css('background-image'));`

Comment: Oops, returned - "url(http://example.com/path/to/photo.jpg)"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Cleaned up the regex to:

```
      img.src = $('.header-image').css('background-image').replace(/(^url\()|(\)$|[\"\'])/g, '');
```

Then wrapped the whole function in .load

```
  var $div = $('.header-image'),
  bg = $div.css('background-image');

  if (bg) {
    var src = bg.replace(/(^url\()|(\)$|[\"\'])/g, ''),
    $img = $('<img>').attr('src', src).on('load', function() {
      // MY FUNCTION HERE
    });
  }
```